# How to use `\phantom` to align equations along a sum operator?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The following MWE shows the following bogus optimization problem with objective and constraints. I'm trying to achieve a visual alignment of the contraints in lines 2 and 3. However, a simple `\phantom` with the `\sum_{...}` as an argument does not create an equal space. I tried out adding `{}` left and right, but that did not seem to do be the solution, either. So the question is this:

**How can I align the constraints on their operators?**
*(Btw: if there is a way to just use the `&` facilities from `align` directly to achieve this, I would be glad to see that as a solution. I do not see how.)*

#### Image

[image: constraints misaligned despite phantom]

#### M-not-WE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\min_{x,y}\ & c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_3 y \\
\mathrm{s.t.}\, & 
  \sum_{i\in \{1,2\}} x_i \geq d \\
& \phantom{\sum_{i\in \{1,2\}}} % what to add here?
               x_i \leq y \ \forall i\in\{1, 2\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\min_{x,y}\ & c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_3 y \\
\mathrm{s.t.}  & \begin{aligned}[t]
                   \sum_{i\in \{1,2\}} x_i & \geq d \\
                   x_i                     &\leq y \ \forall i\in\{1, 2\}
                 \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using stacking a TABstack under the top line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{S}{5pt}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackunder{\displaystyle\min_{x,y}\ c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_3 y}{%
\alignShortstack{%
\,\mathrm{s.t.}\,  \displaystyle\sum_{i\in \{1,2\}} x_i \geq& d \\
x_i \leq& y \ \forall i\in\{1, 2\}
}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `\phantom`, you can do it as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
\min_{x,y}\ & c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_3 y \\
\mathrm{s.t.}\, & 
  \sum_{i\in \{1,2\}} x_i \geq d \\
& \phantom{{}\sum_{i\in \{1,2\}}{}} % what to add here?
               x_i \leq y \ \forall i\in\{1, 2\}
\end{align*}
```

The reason is that there is some space around the sum that separates the sum from its neighbours.  If the `\sum` has no direct neighbours, since it is "alone" within its `\phantom` group, then this space disappears.  If you add empty pairs of braces before and after the sum, the space is reinserted.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a small improvement to @Harish Kumar's solution, using `mathtools`, and two variants for the layout of this equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
                                     & \min_{x,y}\{ c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_3 y\} \\
                                     & \,\mathrm{s. t.}\enspace \begin{aligned}[t]
  \sum_{\mathclap{i\in \{1,2\}}} x_i & \geq d \\
  x_i & \leq y \ \forall i\in\{1, 2\}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
            & \min_{x,y}\{ c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_3 y\} \\
            & \,\mathrm{s. t.}\enspace \begin{aligned}[t]
  x_1 + x_2 & \geq d \\
  x_1,x_2 & \leq y
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    & \min_{x,y}\{ c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_3 y\} \\
    & \,\mathrm{s. t.}\enspace \begin{array}[t]{|l}
  x_1 + x_2 \geq d \\
  x_1,x_2\leq y
  \end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]